# php array of webpages - want to be able to cycle through them with NEXT - PREV links

Tags: php, arrays, navigation

Based on Hunter F's answer, the solution to my problem is almost complete.
Just a couple of tweaks needed.

I modified the code a little and submitted a new question here at: [php array help required - if current array item = 'last or first item' then 'do something'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10932663/1176165)

ORIGINAL MESSAGE:

I want to be able to create a simple navigation bar with PREV and NEXT links that I can use to cycle though a list of pages. The navigation bar will be a php include within all of the pages to be cycled.

So I guess the starting point is to create an array of the pages that need to be cycled though with the PREV  NEXT links.

Such as....

```
$projectlist = array(
        'http://domain.com/monkey/',
        'http://domain.com/tiger/',
        'http://domain.com/banana/',
        'http://domain.com/parrot/',
        'http://domain.com/aeroplane/',
);
```

I want to option to re-order, add or remove the links. So having one self contained master array such as this seems like a logical choice to me as I'll only need to update this one list for any future additions.

Each directory being linked to has it's own index.php file, so I've left the index.php part off from the end of the links as it's not needed...or is it?

...I'm pretty stumped as of how to continue from here.

I guess I need to work out which page within the array I'm currently on, then generate the PREV and NEXT links based on that. So If I entered from 'http://domain.com/parrot/' I would need links to the relevant PREV and NEXT pages.

Any help or information to guide me on this next stage would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$currentPath = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //make sure we don't count any GET variables!
$currentPath = $currentPath[0]; //grab just the path
$projectlist = array(
        '/monkey/',
        '/tiger/',
        '/banana/',
        '/parrot/',
        '/aeroplane/',
);
if(! in_array($currentPath, $projectlist) ) {
    die('Not a valid page!'); //they didn't access a page in our master list, handle error here
}
$currentPageIndex = array_search($currentPath, $projectlist);

if($currentPageIndex == 0) { //if it's on the first page, we want them to go to the last page
    $prevlink = '<a href="'.$projectlist[ sizeof($projectlist)-1].'">Prev</a>';
} else { //otherwise just go to the n-1th page
    $prevlink = '<a href="'.$projectlist[$currentPageIndex-1].'">Prev</a>';
}


if($currentPageIndex  == sizeof($projectlist)-1 ) {     //if we're on the last page, have them go to the first page for "next"
    $nextlink = '<a href="'.$currentPageIndex[0].'">Next</a>';
} else {
    $nextlink = '<a href="'.$projectlist[$currentPageIndex+1].'">Next</a>';
}
```

One thing you may want to consider, is [urlencoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the href targets in the link.

Comment: This is great.  


Current progress is here: http://www.ok-hybrid.com/projects/monkey/  Just a couple of questions.  1) Is it possible for it to loop instead of stopping at the start or end of the array. So when it gets to the first item - the Prev button will link to whatever the last item in the list is. And the same when the last item is active, Instead of stopping the next button will link to the first item. Creating a continuous loop of items.  2) How should I integrate the link variables ($prevlink) ($nextlink)into the anchors of my sub-nav ul.

Comment: Sure! I actually wrote the looping version first and then revised it so that is didn't loop :P.

Answer updated to loop.

Comment: Thanks Hunter F. Just one thing.
Previous button works great. Next button no longer functions at all though.

Comment: Apologies! 

If it's any interest, I wrote "if($nextlink  = sizeof($projectlist)-1 )" instead of "if($currentPageIndex  == sizeof($projectlist)-1 )".