# php array help required - if current array item = 'last or first item' then 'do something'

Tags: php, arrays

Need a little help with this script. It's working but I'd love a way to simplify it a little.

At the moment I have ' if($currentPageIndex == 4) ' I have to manually update the '4' every time I add or remove an item from the projectlist array. What I need is someway of saying 'if($currentPageIndex == **the last item of the array**)' That way I can add / remove items without worrying about updating the number as well.

How should I go about this? I've read up on various options and been trying things out with no luck so far.

Also if possible would the solution be usable on the Prev & Next links as well?
So instead of the **+4** and **-4** it jumps to the first and last item respectively.

Any help much appreciated.

Working demo here: http://www.ok-hybrid.com/projects/monkey/
Code here :

```
<?php

$currentPath = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //make sure we don't count any GET variables!
$currentPath = $currentPath[0]; //grab just the path
$projectlist = array(
        '/projects/monkey/',
        '/projects/tiger/',
        '/projects/parrot/',
        '/projects/banana/',
        '/projects/aeroplane/',
);



if(! in_array($currentPath, $projectlist) ) {
    die('Not a valid page!'); //they didn't access a page in our master list, handle error here.
}

$currentPageIndex = array_search($currentPath, $projectlist);

if($currentPageIndex > 0) { 
    $prevlink = '<a href="'.$projectlist[$currentPageIndex-1].'">Prev</a>';
} else {
    $prevlink = '<a href="'.$projectlist[$currentPageIndex+4].'">Prev</a>';
    }

if($currentPageIndex == 4) { 
    $nextlink = '<a href="'.$projectlist[$currentPageIndex-4].'">Next</a>';
} else {
    $nextlink = '<a href="'.$projectlist[$currentPageIndex+1].'">Next</a>';
}

?>



<ul id="sub-nav">

<li>
<?php
print_r($prevlink);
?>
</li>

<li>
<?php
print_r($nextlink);
?>
</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
sizeof($projectList) - 1
```

to get the desired number

Answer (score 3):

Try `$projectlist[count($projectlist)-1]`

Answer (score 2):

Get the number of elements of your array with [`count()`](http://php.net/count).

```
if ($currentPageIndex == count($projectlist)-1) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $currentPageIndex === end($projectlist) ) {
    //sup
}
```

Comment: I usually prefer the `end()` approach to get the last element because using a count assumes that the array is unmodified. If an element is removed at some point, let's say leaving you with indexes of 0, 1, 3, and 4, `count(...)-1` would yield 3, which is not the last element. And `end()` works with non-numeric indices. In this case, though, you're comparing an index to the actual element.

Comment: @Wiseguy cool but you shouldn't have sparse arrays like that unless they are used as associative arrays with numeric keys. With sequential arrays you always want sequential indices which you can enforce when removing with `array_splice` for example.

Comment: I agree that you don't _want_ gaps in numeric indices, but in the event that somebody does remove an element somewhere, making guesses with `count()` will be inaccurate. Granted, you could always reset indices to sequential numbers using `array_values()`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it fully working using the following code and the help of a friend.
Thanks very much for all the help.

Seems to use a variety of the mentioned steps here. With 'sizeof($projectList) - 1' as mentioned by @Arthur being used to check the link.

```
<?php 

    $currentPath = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //make sure we don't count any GET variables!
    $currentPath = $currentPath[0]; //grab just the path



    $projectlist = array(

    '/projects/monkey/',
    '/projects/tiger/',
    '/projects/parrot/',
    '/projects/banana/',
    '/projects/aeroplane/',
    '/projects/egg/',

    );





    if(! in_array($currentPath, $projectlist) ) {
        die('Not a valid page!'); //they didn't access a page in our master list, handle error here
    }

    $currentPageIndex = array_search($currentPath, $projectlist);

    //echo $currentPageIndex."<Br />";


    //items in array count
    $projectlist_count = count($projectlist);


    if($currentPageIndex > 0) { //make sure it's not the first page
        $prevlink = '<a href="'.$projectlist[$currentPageIndex-1].'">Prev</a>';
            } else {
        $prevlink = '<a href="'.$projectlist[$projectlist_count-1].'">Prev</a>';
            }



    if($nextlink < sizeof($projectlist)-1 ) { //make sure we're not the last page

    if($currentPageIndex+1 >= $projectlist_count)
    {
    //go back to start of array
        $nextlink = '<a href="'.$projectlist[0].'">Next</a>';
    } else {
        $nextlink = '<a href="'.$projectlist[$currentPageIndex+1].'">Next</a>';
    }
    }


    ?>

    <ul id="sub-nav">

    <li>
    <?php
    print_r($prevlink);
    ?>
    </li>

    <li>
    <?php
    print_r($nextlink);
    ?>
    </li>

    </ul>
```